# Умножение элементов массива друг с другом

Tags: javascript

```
let x = [3, 6, -2, -5, 7, 3]

function solution(x) {
  for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {}
}
```

Нужно умножить первый элемент со вторым, третий с четвёртым а пятый с шестым.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var x = [-1, 5, -2, 5, -7, 4, 11];

for (let i = 0; i < x.length; ++i) {
    if (i < x.length-1) {
        console.log(x[i] * x[++i]);
    }
}
```

```js
var x = [-1, 5, -2, 5, -7, 4, 11], num = 0, max =-Infinity;

for (let i = 0; i < x.length; ++i) {
    if (i < x.length - 1) {
        num = x[i] * x[++i];
        if(num > max) {
            max = num;
        }
    }
}
console.log(max);
```

Answer (score 2):

При условии, что кол-во элементов массива - четное.

```js
x = [-1, 5, -2, 5, -7, 4]

function solution(x) {
  // Нам же нужно где-то хранить предыдущий максимум
  var max = -Infinity

  // Пишем += 2, чтобы перескакивать сразу через одно число
  for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i += 2)
    if (max < x[i] * x[i + 1])
      max = x[i] * x[i + 1];

  console.log(max);
}

solution(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
console.log(Math.max(...[3, 6, -2, -5, 7, 3].reduce((acc, curr, idx, arr) => {
  return idx % 2 != 0 ? acc.concat(arr[idx] * arr[idx - 1]) : acc;
}, [])))
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
function solution(x){
    let max = x[0]*x[1]
    for(let i=1; i<x.length-1;i++){
        if(x[i]*x[i+1]>max){
            max=x[i]*x[i+1]
        }
    }
  return max
}
```